# Error al ejecutar aplicacion ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hola estoy creando un proyecto en ASP.NET, al ejecutarlo en el navegador me genera este error: "No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Newtonsoft.Json' ni una de sus dependencias"

Comment: Otra forma de instalarlo es vía Nuget:, Tools -> Options -> Package Manager Console y ya que abrió la consola escribir `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 11.0.2`, en este caso 11.0.2 es la versión más reciente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta la referencia de esa librería Newtonsoft bájate este paquete

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Bájate el zip, descomprimelo y buscas el archivo Newtonsoft.Json.dll para la versión de framework que estás usando y una vez que lo tengas lo vas a importar como referencia en tu proyecto y ya no deberías tener problema